# how to join two table in jpa createquery?

Tags: sql, jpa, netbeans

i want to join two tables that i have but i got an error .
I used this syntaxe :

```
Query qrec2=em.createQuery("Select o from OfPlanifie o Operateur w where o.idOpe =: w.idOpe");
```

but i got this error :

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8025] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [Select o from OfPlanifie o Operateur w where o.idOpe =: w.idOpe], line 1, column 27: unexpected token [Operateur].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(80@[()* loopback of 477:9: (node= join )*])
```

how can i join those two tables ?

Comment: Please stop tagging JPA problems with `[jsf]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma between your two tables `OfPlanifie o, Operateur w`

Additionally, if you want to select all the columns from `OfPlanifie`, you have to do `SELECT o.*` instead of `SELECT o`

Comment: i used this requete `Query qrec2=em.createQuery("Select o from OfPlanifie o,Operateur w where w.matricule=: '5024'");` but didnt respect the where whats the problem with my requete ?

Comment: You are joining two tables but you are not relating them with each other. You should have a `AND o.idOpe =: w.idOpe` at the end (i'm guessing this is the id's that relate these tables)

Comment: If the previous attempt doesn't work, you might want to add a little more context of what you are trying to accomplish, mainly what you are trying to select and how the tables relate to each other.